# Why isn't this image URL Rewrite rule working?

Tags: asp.net, azure, url-rewriting, web-config, imageurl

I have written a URL rewrite to fix images paths to move to a new location for images however it isn't working.

```
<rule name="Artist Images" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/images/$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="https://myserver.blob.core.windows.net/v2/images/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

The expected behavior is that when a request for an image comes in (http://myserver.com/images/sample.jpg) that the new image location
(https://myserver.blob.core.windows.net/v2/images/sample.jpg) is used.

It is a .net application hosted on Azure.  Rule is in the web.config.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Because your condition is not correct, you are putting sign `$` which means end of the string, but this is not correct.

```
<rule name="Artist Images" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^images/(.*)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://myserver.blob.core.windows.net/v2/images/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working but Alexey's answer put us in the right direction.

```
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="/images/(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://artistshare.blob.core.windows.net/images/{C:1}" />
    </rule>
```